# Why is my WCF Data Services method not appearing in the OData collections list?

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-data-services

When I view the root of my WCF Data Services service (http://localhost/MyService.svc/) in a browser I see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<service xml:base="http://localhost/MyService.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
<workspace>
<atom:title>Default</atom:title> 
</workspace>
</service>
```

I would expect to see a list of collections.

When I go to the `$metadata` URL I see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
      <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="1.0">
        <Schema Namespace="MyApp" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">
          <ComplexType Name="Package">
            <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="true" />
          </ComplexType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="MyApp" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">
          <EntityContainer Name="PackageService" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
            <FunctionImport Name="GetQueryablePackages" ReturnType="Collection(MyApp.Package)" m:HttpMethod="GET" />
          </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
      </edmx:DataServices>
    </edmx:Edmx>
```

Why might my `GetQueryablePackages` collection not be appearing?

I'm using these access settings:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service operations (the function import in the EDM) is not exposed in the service document. Only entity sets are exposed there.
If you want your data to be exposed in the service document make an entity set out of it. Depending on the provider model this differs. Typically it means exposing a property of type IQueryable on your context class. Note that T has to be an entity type (must have a key).

Comment: Thanks, I had only exposed methods/operations not a property

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the context definition where you have defined the IQueryable <> properties. There are 2 things that come to my mind: First the properties must be of type IQueryable<> or some type that derives from it. Second, the element type refered by the IQueryable<> must be an entity type i.e. they must have key properties declared in them.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create an extension method like this:

```
public static class TestEntitiesExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Package> GetQueryablePackages(this TestEntities context)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(context.BaseUri, "GetQueryablePackages");
        return context.Execute<Package>(uri);
    }
}
```